# Problems when I try installing license in wmic by cmd batch

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I want to install license for my PC. However, I can't add parameter for the method.

My code:

```
@echo off
for /r "%SystemRoot%\system32\spp\tokens" %%f in (*.xrm-ms) DO  (   
wmic path SoftwareLicensingService WHERE (Version is not null) call InstallLicense License='<%%f'
)
pause
```

Like I want to read all text in the files of "tokens" directory and send it to License parameter.

Here is VB code. I can do it in VB but not in .bat file (Batch)

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) & "\spp\tokens", "*.xrm-ms", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            wmic = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Version FROM SoftwareLicensingService").Get()
            For Each i As String In files
                For Each wmi As ManagementObject In wmic
                    wmi.InvokeMethod("InstallLicense", {File.ReadAllText(i)})
                Next
            Next
```

Thanks all. Sorry for my bad English because I'm Chinese :(

Comment: What is the issue with running your VB code? You can still run that from a batch file, if necessary.

Comment: VB code is okay, no problem. But I want to run the same code in .bat file, only .bat file. Can you help me?

Comment: You should be able to run a VB script directly from a batch file by directly typing its name, with path and extension as required. Alternatively you can also invoke it as an argument to either one of `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`, which are both integral parts of Windows Operating Systems.

Comment: It's VB.NET in Visual Studio

Comment: You don't need to be a programmer to see that this could very easily be a vbscript. However, just in case even that is beyond your capabilities, just compile it and run it. If you're not able to do that either, there is a vbscript already integrated within the OS, `slmgr.vbs`, just run for instance, `%__AppDir__%slmgr.vbs /ilc "%%f"` instead of using the relatively slow `WMIC.exe …` command.

Comment: Is there an error with your code or what are you trying to accomplish?